# Is it allowed to typedef a class template type argument into the same name?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

This seems to compile and even work as expected in MSVC. But is it legal C++ code and is it guaranteed to do what is expected here (that is, export the template type to the struct's users under the same name)?

```
template <typename EnumType>
struct Enum
{
   // There are two hard problems in CS: cache invalidation and naming things.
   typedef EnumType EnumType;
};
```

Comment: Maybe, but as a code-reviewer or a manager I would reject it, because (to me, at least) it is *not immediately obvious* what this construct says, nor why it should be necessary.  It is "nonsensical, on the face of it," for a `typedef` to (appear to ...) define a type as "itself."  So, I would reject the commit on the basis that "you sent your successors on a goose-chase to find out what your code *means,"* without giving adequate business justification for having done so.

Comment: ... (obviously, my comment as-read sounds a good bit more "drastic" and "draconian" than I actually intended it to be.)  **:-)**  I really *am* a fairly nice person. . .

Comment: @MikeRobinson: oh, I'm sure you're a nice person person and nobody would get *fired* over one `typedef`. Right?..    
I get your point and I'd say that's what comments are for.

Comment: *Fired?*  Heh ... "Let he who is without screw-ups among ye, cast the first stone." (While **I** queue-up a copy of the movie, *Liar, Liar!)*  **:-D**  As a former-mentor of mine once said: *"Don't sweat it. It's only ones and zeros."*

Comment: side note: `error: declaration of 'typedef EnumType Enum<EnumType>::EnumType' shadows template parm 'class EnumType'` for `gcc` and `clang`, but the code compiles and works as "expected" for just about every version of Visual Studio .. I'd posit VS is wrong in this scenario however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the type definition is not allowed.

14.6.1 Locally declared names (N4296)

> 6  A template-parameter shall not be redeclared within its scope
>   (including nested scopes).A template-parameter shall not have the same name as
>   the template name. [ Example:
>
> ```
>  
> template<class T, int i> class Y { 
>    int T;  // error: template-parameter redeclared 
>    void f() { 
>        char T; // error: template-parameter redeclared 
>    }
> }; 
>
> template<class X> class X;  // error: template-parameter redeclared
> ```
>
> — end example ]

The `typedef EnumType EnumType` is a redefinition of the template-parameter as typedef-name.